# HTML form is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> Blockquote

Hi i have this problem:
My HTML page is working fine without form, but when i put the form, than i can't select on the 1/2 finle and in finle.

See my code.
How can i solve this probleem?

> Blockquote

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=#0B4C5F>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function groupA(val) {  
        var x = document.getElementById("groupAB");
        x.options[1].value = val;
        x.options[1].text = val;
    } 
         function groupAB(val) {  
        var x = document.getElementById("groupABCD");
        x.options[1].value = val;
        x.options[1].text = val;
    }

        function groupABCD(val) {  
        var x = document.getElementById("groupABCDEFGH");
        x.options[1].value = val;
        x.options[1].text = val;
    }   
   </script>
</head>

<!--=========================================================-->
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<select name="Achtstelfinale1" onchange="groupA(this.value)">
<option value="Select">1e GROUP A</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
</select>
<p></p>

<select name="1/4 Finale 1" id="groupAB" onchange="groupAB(this.value)">
<option value="Select">1/4 Finale 1</option>
<option value="">?</option>
    <option value="">?</option>
</select>
<p></p>

<select name="1/2 Finale" id="groupABCD" onchange="groupABCD(this.value)">
<option value="Select">1/2 FINALE 1</option>
<option value="">?</option>
<option value="">?</option>
</select> 

<p></p>

<select name="Finale" id="groupABCDEFGH" onchange="groupABCDEFGH(this.value)">
<option value="Select">FINALE 1</option>
<option value="">?</option>
<option value="">?</option>
</select> 

<!----------------->
</form>
<!----------------->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `HTML` is malformed. Open the `body` tag after closing the `head`: `</head><body>`. You're opening the `body` on line 2 now, not good.

Comment: you have no values in your option field. moreover your <body> is not proper, you might want to check that.......

Comment: I have tried after head the body   </head><body>  but its stil not working.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve. Apart from the malformed html, you are trying to save the value selected from each droplist back to itself. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user3326912 - Use http://validator.w3.org/ to check your HTML

Comment: it is a part of my code its not the whole of my code.

Comment: if i put the <form action="insert.php" method="post"> away than it works good.             the probleem is the form

Comment: My quistion is why is it not working with form?   without form it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can try and change the html tags. it should look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>`
     #Here goes the Head section(title,links, meta tags and all that stuff)
  </head>

  <body>
     #Here goes the body section
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it was helpfull...
if you have more questions just ask and the stack community will be glad to help you out

Comment: its not working if you add <form>......</form> than its not working i need de form to send de inputs.

Comment: <body>   <form> </form>  </body> this is not working     <body> </body> this works fine

Comment: where do you want to send the inputs?

Comment: i want to send input to here: <form action="insert.php" method="post">